# Laravel - Retrieve the inverse of a many-to-many polymorphic relation (with pagination)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

after some digging I still could not find any solid way to retrieve the inverse of a many-to-many polymorphic relation that allows mixed models results.

Please consider the following:

I have several models that can be "tagged". While it is trivial to retrieve for example `$item->tags`, `$article->tags` and the inverse with `$tag->articles` and `$tag->items` I have no easy way to do something like `$tag->taggables` to return both articles and items in the same collection. Things get even bumpier as I need to use pagination/simple pagination to the query.

I have tried a few workarounds but the best I could put together still looks crappy and limited. Basically:

- I queried the DB once per "taggable";
- put all in a single big collection;
- passed the collection to a phpleague/fractal transformer (my API uses it) that returns different json values depending on the parsed models.

The limits of this approach is that building a pagination is a nightmare and fractal "include" options can't be used out of the box.

Can anyone help me? I'm currently using Laravel 5.1.

There is not much magic in my current code. Faking and simplifying it to make it short:

**From the api controller:**

```
$tag = Tag::findOrDie($tid);
$articles = $tag->cms_articles()->get();
$categories = $tag->cms_categories()->get();
$items = $tag->items()->simplePaginate($itemsperpage);

$taggables = Collection::make($articles)->merge($categories);
// Push items one by one as pagination would dirt the collection struct.
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $taggables->push($item);
}

return $this->respondWithCollection($taggables, new TaggableTransformer);
```

*Note: using simplePaginate() is there only because I would like all articles and categories to be shown on first page load while the number of items are so many that need pagination.*

**From the Transformer class:**

```
public function transform($taggable)
{
    switch (get_class($taggable)) {
        case 'App\Item':
            $transformer = new ItemTransformer;
            break;
        case 'App\CmsArticle':
            $transformer = new CmsArticleTransformer;
            break;
        case 'App\CmsCategory':
            $transformer = new CmsCategoryTransformer;
            break;
    }
    return $transformer->transform($taggable);
}
```

Please consider that the other transformers are simply returning arrays of data about the models they correlate with. If you use [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) you would easily spot that nested "included" models would not be applied.

**Nothing fancy for the Tag model:**

```
class Tag extends Model
{   
    protected $morphClass   = 'Tag';
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'language_id');

    public function cms_articles() {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\CmsArticle', 'taggable');
    }

    public function cms_categories() {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\CmsCategory', 'taggable');
    }

    public function items() {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Item', 'taggable');
    }

    // Would love something like this to return inverse relation!! :'(
    public function taggables() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I am also considering the option to do 3 separate calls to the API to retrieve articles, categories and items in three steps. While in this particular scenario this might make sense after all, I would still need to deal with this particular inverse relation headache with another part of my project: notifications. In this particular case, notifications would have to relate to many different actions/models and I would have to retrieve them all in batches (paginated) and sorted by model creation date...

Hope this all makes sense. I wonder if a completely different approach to the whole inverse "polymorphic" matter would help.

Kind regards,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes. I was down your path not all that long ago. I had the same nightmare of dealing with resolving the inverse of the relationship of polymorphic relationships.

Unfortunately polymorphic relationships haven't been given much attention in the Laravel ecosystem. From afar they look like unicorns and rainbows but soon you're fighting things like this.

Can you post an example of a `$thing->taggable` for a better picture? Think it may be solvable with a dynamic trait + accessor magic.

Comment: Tried to add a few considerations and some example code... I wonder if this whole thing makes sense or (apart from implementation difficulties) there are other reasons why it is not in the ORM (eg. best practices).

Comment: Dylan, how did you happen to solve this? Should I approach this in a completely different way?