# How can I define the inverse polymorphic many-to-may relationship in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel here. Some confusion regarding eloquent relationship.

I'm trying to achieve this : [Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkxf4.jpg)

Here's the [ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLbas.jpg)

- 1 Question can be any type (multiple-choices/ordering/matching/etc.)
- 1 choice AKA 1 row in each {type} table can be mapped to only 1 question

In the ER-diagram the red hilighted part were my first thought (Polymorphic 1-to-Many) 
but now I changed it to many-to-may with pivot table instead:

[pivot table]

*question_id* | *choiceable_id* | *choiceable_type*

However, the question is: **How do I define this type of relationship in the models ?**

- **Is Polymorphic Many-To-Many the correct type?**
- **What is the correct way to get to the choices given a random question?**

Because if I understand the doc. correctly, I need to call each type and specify the table inside, but I feel it's a little messy...

```
// Question Model
function get_multiple_choices {
return $this->morphedByMany('App\TypeMultipleChoice', 'choiceable')

function get_ordering_choices {
return $this->morphedByMany('App\TypeOrderingChoice', 'choiceable')

...
```

is this code correct ? And I still don't know about the choices for random question part. Somehow I feel like there should be a simpler way to get those choices.

**EDIT**

Ok, let me re-phrase it.

Can I use / How to use:

```
// Question Model
function choices {
   // $this->MorphTo,MorphedByMany, etc. ?
}
```

instead of

```
// Question Model
function get_multiple_choices {}
function get_matching_choices {}
function get_ordering_choices {}
... x 4-5 more times
```

Comment: Rule of thumb in stackoverflow: Don't ask a question in stackoverflow whose answer is the first result searching it in google.

Comment: May I ask, which one, specifically ?  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633604/laravel-retrieve-the-inverse-of-a-many-to-many-polymorphic-relation-with-pagi) ?

Comment: No. I'm not saying the first result in stackoverflow. I'm saying literally THE FIRST RESULT, which is a page in laravel.com. The "I'm feeling lucky" result.

Comment: Are you referring to the 5.8 documentation?  That's exactly why I call this question 'reverse'. Because I want the reverse of what they're giving example in the doc.  To use the doc as example:  I want tags->taggables()  not tags->posts() or tags->videos(), if that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'hasMany' for getting many-to many relationships

```
public function multipleChoices
{
    Return $this->hasMany('App\TypeMultipleChoice', 'choiceable');
}
```